# How to get the time in Python

Tags: python, time

## How do I get and print the current time in Python?

I'm following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw) and want to print the current time in my python script. I can not reproduce what is thought in the toturial. The current time is not printed.

Here is my current code for the Python script:

#### main.py:

```
def printTime():
  print("The time is"+time+"right now");
printTime();
```

I want to achieve is

- That the time variable is a variable that equals the current time
- To find a way to get the current time printed

Comment: Copy paste the title of your question in the web search provider of your choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `datetime.now()` method of `datetime` module:-

```
import datetime
time=datetime.datetime.now()

def printTime():
  print("The time is",time,"right now");
printTime()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime.now()` from `datetime` module to get the current date and time like this,

```
import datetime
current_date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Plugging in this to your function,

```
import datetime

def printTime():
  current_date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
  print(f"The time is {current_date_time} right now")

printTime()
```

If you are not interested in the date part and only want the time part, you can extract time component from the datetime object like this

```
import datetime

def printTime():
  current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time() # get only time component
  print(f"The time is {current_time} right now")

printTime()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and it was very quick as well

Comment: Really doubt that `"The time is" + current_date_time` is going to work.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli fixed that now......

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime to get current time.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

#This is how I usually do this

```
import time;
CurrentTime= time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print ("Date/Time:", CurrentTime)
```